# Adding a list view inside a listitem

Tags: android, android-fragments, listadapter

I am using list fragment with a list header and need to add a set of list inside the first list item. 
[image: something like following]

I am using custom list adapter to load the list items. Now for List Item 1 - I need to add a subview on top of list item from within the list adapter. How should I go about this? I am not sure if expandable list item is what I wanna use here.

My custom adapter's getView looks something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder = null;
   int type = getItemViewType(position);

   if (convertView == null) {
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   switch (type) {

    case TYPE_LIST_ITEM_1:
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.id.list_item_one, null);
        /* add code */                          
        /* add another list adapter? */
        break;

    case TYPE_LIST_ITEM_OTHERS:
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_other, null);
        /* add code for below list */
        break;

    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
   } 
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
   }

   return convertView;
  }
```

What would be a optimal way of going about it, without losing the header view which uses

```
     myListView.addHeaderView(myHeaderView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work around by using the following code, putting it here:

When updating the custom list adapter (ex: myCustomListAdapter) using base adapter you can define different method to add list item and sublist items:

```
myCustomAdapter.addListItem(new ListItemObject (item));
myCustomAdapter.addSublistItem(new SublistItemObject (item));
```

And then use the getView to inflate different layouts and use your custom object to identify what you wanna do with them and how you want to display them. While the list adapter identify as all part of the list view.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    final SuperListItemObject item = (SuperListItemObject) getItem(position);


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        switch (type) {

        case TYPE_LIST_ITEM:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview); 
            break;

        case TYPE_SUBLIST_ITEM:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sublist_item, null);
            holder.subtext=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);  
            break;

        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(item instanceof ListItemObject){
        holder.text.setText("this is list item");
        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    //your code for list item
    }

    if(item instanceof SublistItemObject){
        holder.subtext.setText("this is sublist item");
        holder.subtext.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    //your code for sublist item
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Here the layout which you inflate for sublist can be customized using layout_marginLeft=20dp and layout_marginRight=20dp

Comment: i have the similiar issue , list item 1 ,list item 2 ,list item 3 and so on , list item 1 can contain multiple sublist item , but i am unable to get your above code ,can you please provide with little bit more explanation with the more code

Answer (score 2):

A `ScrollView` in a `ScrollView` isn't possible on Android without major bugs, Google says to not do it. You could have a `LinearLayout` inside of your list item (with its `orientation` set to `vertical`) and manually use `addView()` to add views to the LinearLayout that will be displayed with the layout's set orientation.

Comment: you could use an XML template for the views which you inflate and pass to addView() instead of doing everything programatically.

Comment: Yes, I was heading in that direction but addView() didnt work for me within fragments/inner class. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure i understand what you are trying to do , but if i understand correctly ... :

a listView within a listView is highly un-recommended by google, as it causes weird scrolling and unpredictable UI to the user.

please don't use such a thing.

however, if there are just a few items inside, use a normal container without any scrolling.

also, an alternative to what you are doing is [expandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: I do realize, using listview within listview is bad practice. That's why I am stuck. I cant add just a container since I dunno how many would be needed each time. Its unpredictable each time.

Comment: have you considered using 2 screens or 2 fragments ? or maybe expand the item when you click it? how about a horizontal listView as the sub items container? a listview usually shows items that don't use a lot of the screen height.

Comment: I considered those options, but it wasnt exactly what I needed.

Comment: I somehow made it worked, by tweaking my objects being passed to the adapter and using marginLayoutLeft / marginLayoutRight. And now they work like just another listitem on that listfragment and display the way I needed. Thanks!

Comment: wait, so you do use a listView within a listView ?

Comment: nope, it is just another list item like list item 1 and list item 2 (in the image) except now sublist items are (according to adapter) list item 2/3/4 likewise. But it displays them differently after checking the object passed to the list adapter and if it is sublist item type then it displays it differently. And will continue to have its own actions and also buttons (in my case).

Comment: not sure i understand. can you please post some code (or xml) ?